# Is there a way to collapse whitespace before script open delimiter in php?

Tags: php

In php, if a closing script tag `?>` is followed by whitespace up to and including a new line character, the whitespace is removed from the output.

This helps remove extra blank lines from the HTML. However the output still looks messy because the white space **before** the opening `<?php` delimiter is not collapsed.

Is there a way to control this behavior to either enable it for both delimiters or disable it altogether?

Comment: You could generate all the source in one `<?php` block then output it. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php `This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script.`

Comment: @chris85 The purpose is to make editing templates easier, partially for me, but, also for the designer. I separate my php files in logic controllers and template views, with the views containing no logic besides basic flow control statements.